# Flutter text widgets to use

Tags: flutter

Need help to understand if Flutter can help us.

We are looking at flutter for app development for a rewrite of a js electron for desktop and js webview for mobiles.

It is basically a sophisticated reading app with multiple dictionaries and searching algorithms and other features specific to an Asian language and also English parallel translations.

We want to display Religious books in the native Unicode language with extensive dictionary support.
The books will have some bold and heading text markup (the markup style can be any format but we currently use html styles).

The books will be in a sqlite DB and streamed to the user.

The books will be stored in the db by paragraph.. We need to display this in a built up flow to the user.

The books will have some items which can be displayed or hidden upon user request but we can regenerate the display if needed.  (currently it does live through js).

The books will need to communicate if a tap() or Textselect() event has been called (we often tap to select a word and it goes to a custom dictionary).

Searching for strings in the book will be done by paragraph and then we need to 1) highlight the text and bring the user to that text.

We wish to implement infinite scroll or "Lazy load" as the books are very big and often text processing to change the native script font is involved before display.

**Conclusion**

I think this captures much of what we want to have.
I have done some work in flutter, but i'm very new to it.
It seems that there is a SelectableText.rich widget and perhaps we could connect them together in an infinite scroll list widget from pub.dev

For hiding the page numbers.. and alt readings, it is fine to reload the book and remove those as we feed the widget with text.

There are a few html widgets, but I'm not sure if it gives select and tap events.

Can Flutter do this for us?
Are there packages that I'm not aware of?
Am I heading in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test called https://github.com/bksubhuti/mydbtest
It seems to work.. the selecting of texts are off by a few bits, but it is workable..

However, I have found a full app for my purpose already written in flutter with a sqlite philosophy already working.  The dev and myself are in touch and the project has been upgraded to null safety.  Flutter is awesome.  In about a month.. part time.. I have learned flutter and written my first app and submitted it to the play store called Buddhist Sun.  (pending approval).  I use sqflite and the multiplatform eq for getting cities.. the db search of cities  was more of a flutter tutorial for me than purpose.

https://github.com/bksubhuti/buddhist_sun

Flutter will be the language of the future.  I'm so amazed at how great it works and all the packages on pub.dev